# GridLayoutManager column height issue

Tags: android, xml, gridview, android-design-library

I want to achieve same layout height for all the columns of the list. I am using GridLayoutManager

[image: preview]

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mCon,2 );
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

and this is the column xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="1dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/padding_2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userimg"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/user_profile_default" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/nameRL"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userimg"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.skcsllp.mutterfly.widgets.MfTextView
                    android:id="@+id/u_name"
                    style="@style/textview.bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:text="Akshay"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_text_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/location1"
                    android:layout_width="7dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/u_name"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/location_pin" 
                    />

                <com.skcsllp.mutterfly.widgets.MfTextView
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/u_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/location1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/location1"
                    android:text="2.5km"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_extra_small_10" 
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nameRL"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_bottmon_tab" 
                />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rel_first"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="80dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ln_cart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/padding_24dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/padding_24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cart_icon"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_2dp" 
                    />

                <com.skcsllp.mutterfly.widgets.MfTextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_name"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                    android:text="Laptop "
                    android:textColor="@color/primary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ln_cal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ln_cart"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/padding_24dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/padding_24dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_cal"
                    />

                <com.skcsllp.mutterfly.widgets.MfTextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                    android:text=" 7 july - 8 july"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_text_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small_14"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_rl"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_bottmon_tab" 
            />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_ln_sec"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_second"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number_of_provider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offer_sent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="offersent"
                android:visibility="gone" 
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/accept_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/padding_32dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/padding_32dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/check_mark"
                android:gravity="center" 
                />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Both columns has same height but **bottom tick** is getting placed differently when item name is bigger. can anyone suggest me how to fix this. thanks

Comment: which one is bottom tick? And some screenshots.

Comment: second column green tick is lifted upwards compared to first one

Answer (score 1):

Since, you want all your `main_rl` to be of the same height, depending on your use-cases, one of the ways to achieve that would be to fix its height to a sufficiently large value and let the `android:gravity="center"` handle the rest:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_first"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
        android:gravity="center">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should work for most cases. If I REALLY wished to go overboard with this method, I'd find the larger height between adjacent cards (via `ViewTreeObserver` at runtime) and then set that value to the other. I doubt that is needed.

Comment: I tried that but its stretching the view unnecessarily since min is 100dp. can you please go in detail about viewTreeObserver

Comment: @ndeokar Like I said, you can also go with `80dp`, your `minHeight`. With `ViewTreeObserver` we can identify right when your views are about to be drawn (via the callback `onPreDraw()`). There we can call `getHeight()` on required views to get their calculated height and then within the same function we specify the new layout params (based on the max height we find using `getHeight()`) to our views. This definitely is a bit of work both logic wise and performance wise.

Comment: Thanks ! i would definitely try this on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `android:layout_below="@+id/view_second"` to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to make bottom tick always on bottom of parent layout. I actually do not have ide to check my answer is correct, sory for that :(

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_ln_sec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_second"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```